# syntax error with clause 'for' in the last snapshot WSO2 CEP 4.0.0

Tags: for-loop, time, wso2

I downloaded the last wso2cep-4.0.0-SNAPSHOT from jenkins (https://wso2.org/jenkins/view/product-builds/job/product-cep  #619 (22-giu-2015 22.40.10) and I'm triing a simple execution plan:

```
@Plan:name('ExecutionPlan')

define stream stream3 (id string, val string);

define stream stream4 (id string, val string);

from stream3#window.timeBatch(10 seconds)
select id,val
insert into stream4
for expired-events;
```

when I validate the code I get this error:

extraneous input 'for' expecting {, ';'}

if I delete the last row it is ok. I tried the same execution plan in the 3.1.0 stable and there are no problems. Why?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your query as below,

from stream3#window.timeBatch(10 seconds)
select id,val 
insert expired events into stream4;